# Move Gift Options to correct location

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I have enabled Gift Option message in Magento 2. But upon viewing the `checkout/cart` it seems weird that the Gift Option is not in their correct location. How can I fix this? What xml should I modify? Below is how it looks like

[image]

Notice the Gift Option of the first item is located in the second item. While the gift option of the last item is located at the bottom most part. How can I fix this? Is it an xml fix?